# Preview auto-open of PNG files after being downloaded from Safari

Tags: macos, safari, preview

How can I make PNG files be automatically opened after being downloaded from Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be related to a preference in Safari rather than Preview.

Open Safari, then Preferences, then go to the General tab. If the option to 'Open "safe" files after downloading' is checked, uncheck it and that may stop Preview opening the downloaded image automatically.